# How to instantiate PrivateType of inner private class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private-members

I was trying to setup a unit test for a private inner class, but had very little success:

```
namespace Stats.Model
{
  public class DailyStat
  {
    private class DailyStatKey // The one to test
    {
      private DateTime date;
      public DateTime Date 
      { 
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value.Date; }
      }

      public StatType Type { get; set; }

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
        return Date.Year * 1000000 +
               Date.Month * 10000 +
               Date.Day * 100 +
               (int)Type;
      }

      public override bool Equals(object obj)
      {
        DailyStatKey otherKey = obj as DailyStatKey;
        if (otherKey == null)
          return false;
        return (this.Date == otherKey.Date && this.StatType == otherKey.StatType);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
PrivateType statKeyType = new PrivateType("Stats.Model", "Stats.Model.DailyStat.DailyStatKey");
```

as well as

```
PrivateType statKeyType = new PrivateType("Stats.Model", "DailyStat.DailyStatKey");
```

To no avail.

The assembly's name is "Stats.Model", and to me the type name looks correct too, but I just get an exception: "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type"

So what am I doing wrong ?

PrivateType, to the best of my knowledge, is reflection based, and I'd guess it's pretty much intended for this scenario, as you cannot have a private class directly beneath a namespace.

EDIT:

Added full implementation of DailyStatKey. What I want to test is the uniqueness of my GetHashCode method. As you can see I try to fit a date + type into a single int.

Comment: In C#, "new SomeType(args)" does not use Reflection.  Instead, it is always a constructor call, and calls one of the available constructors.  In your example code, there is no constructor, so the only constructor available is the default constructor (null constructor--constructor with no args).  You cannot call this from the outside either because the class is private.  So you are right that you need reflection.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198912/use-reflection-or-a-property-when-unit-testing

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you mention the part about constructors ?
What I mean about PrivateType using Reflection, is that it uses it to access the private class/methods. (This is pretty obvious from the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privatetype(VS.80).aspx as it requires ReflectionPermission.


As for the related question, yes I'm aware one shouldn't test private classes, but since it's only used internally and it's crucial that the GetHashCode always returns something unique, I figured I'd better do a test.

Comment: D'oh!  You're right.  I misread the code.  I was thinking you put "new DailyStatKey(...)" for some reason.

Comment: Fair enough, then I get it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution myself:

```
var parentType = typeof(DailyStat);
var keyType = parentType.GetNestedType("DailyKeyStat", BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
//edited to use GetNestedType instead of just NestedType

var privateKeyInstance = new PrivateObject(Activator.CreateInstance(keyType, true));

privateKeyInstance.SetProperty("Date", DateTime.Now);
privateKeyInstance.SetProperty("Type", StatType.Foo);

var hashCode = (int)privateKeyInstance.Invoke("GetHashCode", null);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use PrivateType directly as well:

```
PrivateType statKeyType = new PrivateType("Stats.Model", "Stats.Model.DailyStat+DailyStatKey");
```

Nested classes have a string format that's different from their namespace (which is Stats.Model.DailyStat.DailyStatKey) so the usage isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is private the only class that can create the instance is `DailyStat` itself. Unless you make it non private reflection (activator) would be your only choice if you want to create the class although that would not be a good idea as you wont be able to use it directly unless you are able to cast it to a public enough type or interface

EDIT:

Since you are trying to do this for unit testing then effectively you shouldnt test this class as it is private. You would only be able to test it through any public interface of `DailyStat`.

Comment: Hmm but PrivateType does use Reflection AFAIK, so I still don't see why it's a problem.

Besides what was PrivateType made for, if not this ? You can't have a private class directly in a namespace.

Comment: You can only have private inner classes which are useful if you want to encapulate functionality only the outer class will use. You can only use new PrivateType() inside the class it is coded within. No refelction is involved. I mentioned reflection since it can be used to instatitate private classes and call private methods outside the class

Comment: It's exactly for encapsulating functionality which is solemnly used inside the outer class. So that part is alright.

I'll check whether PrivateType works within the outer class.

Comment: Well figured out how to get the type now:
var parentType = typeof(DailyStat);
var keyType = parentType.NestedType("DailyKeyStat", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

Works like a charm :-)

Comment: @apollodude217: Hadn't thought about that, it's posted now and I'll Accept it when the 2 day limit is gone.

Answer (score -2):

You can code a public "GetDailyStatKey" method on parent class.

```
public class DailyStat
{
    private class DailyStatKey // The one to test 
    {
    }
    public DailyStatKey GetDailyStatKey()
    {
        return new  DailyStatKey();
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
DailyStat v = new DailyStat();
var x =  v.GetDailyStatKey();
```

Comment: That is impossible because the type you are returning is invisible to the calling side. Also you can just set DailyStatKey to public if you want this.

Comment: Like Dykam says it won't work, plus I could just go with a public inner class - which I really don't want.

Comment: You can put an interface on the inner class which is public so you can control what is visible to the world

Comment: @aqwert, what's the benefit of that? You can also limit exposure in the class itself.