# How to create a class object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class named `ErrorMessageTest` which is has some properties.

I have another class named ErrorHandlerTest and a method called `HandleErrorTest`, which will take the above as parameters and create a class in below structure.

```
public class ErrorMessageTest
{
    private string EventId;
    private string TransactionId;
    private string Timestamp;
    private string Component;
    private string UserId;
    private string Message;
    private string Exception;
}

public static class ErrorHandlerTest
{
    public static void HandleErrorTest(string EventId, string TransactionId, 
                                       DateTime Timestamp, string Component,
                                       string UserId)
    {

    }
}
```

I need to return an `ErrorMessage` object but I don't know how to create an instance of it.

Comment: What is `ErrorMessage`? Do you mean `ErrorMessageTest` instead? What's wrong with the usual mechanism for creating an instance of a class, i.e. `new ErrorMessage()` or `new ErrorMessageTest`, as appropriate)? How do you intend to _return_ anything from your `HandleErrorTest()` method, given that the method is declared as returning `void`? I don't find this question clear at all.

Comment: You can't return an ErrorMessage from a void method. What is an ErrorMessage? Are you missing some code? Where do you want to create and return an ErrorMessage?

Comment: Note to those answering: **`HandleErrorTest` is `static`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few basic mistakes.

First of all, all your *fields* are private. Instead, you'll want to create public *properties* instead:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } 
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in your `HandleError` method, you need a return type of `ErrorMessage` instead of `void`. `void` means *no return type*. If you also want to make it a `static` class, you do so as follows:

```
public static class ErrorHandler
{
    public static ErrorMessage HandleError(string eventId, string transactionId, 
                                           DateTime timeStamp, string component,
                                           string userId)
    {
        return new ErrorMessage
        {
            EventId = eventId,
            TransactionId = transactionId,
            Timestamp = timeStamp,
            Component = component,
            UserId = userId
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `ErrorMessage` class

Comment: Where did you get the declaration for `ErrorMessage`? That is, the class your code example is returning? That class doesn't exist in the original question. You seem to have just arbitrarily renamed the `ErrorMessageTest` class.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Look at the code now, you'll see it.

Comment: There is now, but that is not the class in the OP's code

Comment: @SanD That's the same class as in the OP's code, simply refactored to *make sense*.

Comment: But are you sure that he actually named the class correctly in his question and not in his code?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov, seems this will be helpful but one more question is, can i serialize ErrorMessage object after returning it, because i have to send this to windows Service bus, at present i don't  have the knowledge on service bus, but it will accept only serialized data, that's what i read in google,

Comment: @SanD The class name doesn't matter. He can call it whatever he wants. I was demonstrating how to structure the class correctly. He can call it `Foo` if he wants.

Comment: @Chiranjeevi I think you need to do some homework first about how to serialize data in C#. There are many ways and forms to do so, you need to choose the right one. Binary, XML, JSON, etc..

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: Yes i will do that, thanks for your answer, as well as correcting the queston based on comments below.

Comment: Honestly the propensity to jump on a reasonable post is annoying. @YuvalItzchakov is the only answer who bothered to notice they were trying to instantiate a static class on the first post of their answer (which would obviously fail at compile time) and provides good advice in a clear and concise manner.

Answer (score 2):

In such cases where you have to set private fields for testing, I suggest to use the [PrivatObject-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) from the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting package. It has a [SetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243988.aspx) method which allows you to set private fields.

This post [How to instantiate PrivateType of inner private class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200875/how-to-instantiate-privatetype-of-inner-private-class) disusses the topic of PrivatObject and PrivateType. PrivateObject is used for accessing private members of instances whereas PrivateType is used for static class members.

But be aware that setting the private fields via reflection, like the PrivateObject does, has the drawback, that your test needs knowledge about the internals of the ErrorMessage class which is a violation of the principle to test against the contract (public class members, interface) of a type.

Answer (score 0):

Though your all variables are private in ErrorMessageTest Class. you need to make it publicly available.
you can do it like-

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public string EventId;
    public string TransactionId;
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public string Component;
    public string UserId;
    public string Message;
    public string Exception;
}

public class ErrorHandlerTest
{
    public static ErrorMessage HandleErrorTest(string EventId, string TransactionId,
                                       DateTime Timestamp, string Component,
                                       string UserId)
    {
        return new ErrorMessage()
        {
            Component = Component,
            EventId = EventId,
            Timestamp = Timestamp,
            TransactionId  = TransactionId,
            UserId = UserId

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns an instance of `ErrorMessageTest`, not `ErrorMessage` as the question requests

Comment: @PeterDuniho, right. But where's the ErrorMessage class he is asking for ?

Comment: you are right here also, in fact i read it as ErrorMessageTest earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to return an **ErrorMessageTest** class inside your method HandleErrorTest().:).If so just change the return type of the method to **ErrorMessageTest** like

```
    public static ErrorMessageTest HandleErrorTest(string EventId, string TransactionId, 
                                   DateTime Timestamp, string Component,
                                   string UserId)
{

}
```

and create an instance of the class ErrorMessageTest and form the object to return like this

```
  return new ErrorMessageTest
 {
     EventId = eventId,
     TransactionId = transactionId,
     Timestamp = timeStamp,
     Component = component,
     UserId = userId
 };
```

now your method will look like

```
    public static ErrorMessageTest HandleErrorTest(string EventId, string TransactionId, 
                                   DateTime Timestamp, string Component,
                                   string UserId)
        {

  return new ErrorMessageTest
    {
     EventId = eventId,
     TransactionId = transactionId,
     Timestamp = timeStamp,
     Component = component,
     UserId = userId
    };
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

In ErrorHandlerTest to instantiate ErrorMessageTest add:

```
ErrorMessageTest errorMessageTest = new ErrorMessageTest();
```

this will create an instance of the class ErrorMessageTest, and can be accessed trough local variable errorMessageTest with which you can do as you please.

edit : wrong name copy pasted, replaced with errorMessageTest

Comment: Well, no, ErrorHandlerTest is a static class